# Ping between dockers by hostname

Tags: docker

I want to know how to ping between dockers containers by hostname. I create a network with `network create` command. I'm running bot containers with these commands:

```
docker run --hostname=app --net=custom container1 

docker run --hostname=web --net=custom container2
```

But when I enter to the first container with

```
docker exec -it name /bin/bash
```

and then run 
`ping web`, the response is

> ping: web: Name or service not known

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hostname is not used with docker's built-in DNS resolution. You can resolve container name, service name (in a compose file), and any network aliases you provide. All of these values are controlled by docker outside of the container, where the hostname could potentially be modified inside of the container outside of the view of docker.

To use container name, all you need is:

```
docker run --name=app --net=custom container1 

docker run --name=web --net=custom container2
```

Or for network alias, you can try:

```
docker run --network-alias=app --net=custom container1 

docker run --network-alias=web --net=custom container2
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, since I'm very new to docker I don't know how to "reuse" the same name everytime I run the container. The first time it runs ok, but on the second time it says "ocker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/web" is already in use by container "xxxxx". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.". When I run docker image ls I can't see the "web" image to "docker rmi -f" it and run again with the same name.

Comment: @NicolásSantisteban Delete your old container with `docker rm web` or run it so that it deletes as soon as it stops with `docker run --rm --name=web --net=custom container2`

Comment: You can see all containers (not just the running ones) with `docker container ls -a` (or `docker ps -a` for the old syntax).

Comment: Keep in mind the image is a spec to create containers. You build an image, and then you run that image as one or more containers. So when looking for containers, use the `docker container` commands rather than `docker image` commands.

Comment: Apart from answer my question, you helped me understanding those terms, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Giving a hostname to a system or container is one thing, but having it actually resolve from other systems/containers is another.

Take a look at the [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E75728/html/section_rsr_p2z_fp.html) on making docker containers communicate with each other.

Long story short, you can take one of two approaches:

### Add a Link to The Run Command

For this approach, simply change `--hostname` to `--name`, and add the link option as follows:

```
docker run --name=web --net=custom container1
docker run --name=app --net=custom container2 --link web:web
```

This will modify the hosts file in the second container to link the hostname "web" to its containers ip.

### Change The Hosts File Directly

In /etc/hosts, add the following lines in the appropriate containers

```
in app container: <IP_WEB_CONTAINER>  web
in web container: <IP_APP_CONTAINER>  app
```

the hostnames should now resolve properly.

Comment: I don't know if use Link is a good idea since is a deprecated option

Comment: Links are deprecated and don't handle replacing containers well since the link is hardcoded in the /etc/host file of the container rather than being dynamically updated with docker's DNS.